# Using for statement to find the greatest of four given integers?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int, int, int, int);

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf("Enter 4 numbers -");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int greatest, i = 0;
    int num[4] = { a, b, c, d };
    greatest = num[0];
    while (i >= 3) {
        if (greatest <= num[i]) {
            greatest = num[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

So I tried using a for loop to compare every number to a variable `greatest`.
**But the answer for the greatest integer is always the first integer.**

Comment: Thanks a lot.I didn't see that error.

Comment: "I didn't see that error": it's normal not to see errors straight away and it's a sign to start debugging. Stepping through this using a debugger would lead you quickly to the realisation that your loop body is never executed.

Comment: There isn't even a for loop in your code!?

Comment: initial value of i is 0 and condition to run while loop is when i is greater or equal to 3 so while won't get executed as condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: is there any reason why you want to use a loop? The simple way is just `return max(max(a, b), max(c, d))`

Answer (score 2):

In `max_of_four`:

`while (i >= 3)` is never true because you start with `i` being 0, and 0 is not greater than or equal to 3. Perhaps you meant `while (i <= 3)`, but you would normally write this loop using `for` rather than `while`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    if (greatest <= num[i]) greatest = num[i];
```

Comment: More idiomatic would be `for (int I = 1; I < 4; i++)` — which uses the upper bound explicitly (rather than the upper bound minus one), and which avoids retesting element 0 of the array.  You could refine things further by assigning value to `greatest` and then only putting the other three values in the array and testing the smaller array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `while` loop condition. The condition should have been `while(i<=3)`.

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b ,int c, int d) {

    int greatest,i = 0;
    int num[4] = {a, b, c, d};
    greatest = num[0];
    while(i <= 3) {
        if(greatest <= num[i]) {
            greatest = num[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

Comment: For your code, too, the upper bound is more naturally expressed as `while (i < 4)`, using the explicit upper bound rather than the upper bound minus one.  And the same refinement that I outlined in my comment to what is currently the other answer applies here too.  In general, using a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop is a good idea when the loop is simply iterating over an area.

Answer (score 0):

The test `while (i >= 3)` is incorrect, you probably meant to write this instead:

```
while (i <= 3)
```

Note that `for` loops are much more readable as you can group the initialization, test and increment of `i` in a single line:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (greatest <= num[i]) {
        greatest = num[i];
    }
}
```

Note also that it is more consistent to use `i < 4` instead of `i <= 3` to make the array length more obvious.

Also, you do not need an array with 4 entries: 3 entries suffice as you initialize `greatest` to the first value already.

Here is a modified version:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int greatest = a;
    int num[3] = { b, c, d };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (greatest < num[i]) {
            greatest = num[i];
        }
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

Finally, constructing an array to determine the maximum value among 4 integers is a bit of an overkill. Here is a much simpler version:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    if (a < b) a = b;   // a = max(a, b)
    if (c < d) c = d;   // c = max(c, d)
    if (a < c) a = c;   // a = max(a, c)
    return a;
}
```

If you must use a `for` loop, you can just wrap 3 simple tests into a dummy `for` statement:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    for (;;) {
        if (a < b) a = b;
        if (c < d) c = d;
        if (a < c) a = c;
        return a;
    }
}
```